# Compare and swap with and without garbage collector

Tags: garbage-collection, atomic, compare-and-swap

How does CAS works? How does it work with garbage collector? Where is the problem and how does it work without garbage collector?

I was reading a presentation about CAS and using it on "write rarely, read many" problem and there was said, that use of CAS is convenient while you can use garbage collector, but there is problem (not specified) while you can not use garbage collector.

Can you tell me something about this? If you can sum up principle of CAS at first, it would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so CAS is an atomic instruction, that is there is special hardware support for it. 
Its main use is to not use locks at all when implementing your data structures and other operations, since using locks, if a thread takes a page fault, a cache miss or is being descheduled by the OS for instance the thread takes the lock with it and all the rest of the threads are blocked. This obviously yields serious performance issues.
CAS is the core of [lock-free programming](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LbOB_moUa94) and [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kH59-vLMNys) and [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=c1gO9aB9nbs).

CAS basically is the following:

```
CAS(CURRENT_VALUE, OLD_VALUE, NEW_VALUE) <=> 
if CURRENT_VALUE==OLD_VALUE then CURRENT_VALUE = NEW_VALUE
```

You have a variable (e.g. class variable) and you have no clue if it was modified or not by other threads in the time you read from it and you want to write to it. 
CAS helps you here on the write part since this CAS is done atomically (in hardware) and no lock is being implemented there, thus even if your thread goes to sleep the rest of the threads can operate on your data structure.

The issue with CAS on non-GC systems is the [ABA problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ABA_problem) and an example is the following:

```
You have a single linked list: HEAD->A->X->Y->Z
Thread 1: let's read A: localA = A; localA_Value = A.Value (let's say 5)
Thread 2: let's delete A: HEAD->A->X->Y->Z
Thread 3: let's add a new node at start (the malloc will find the right spot right were old A was): HEAD->A'->X->Y->Z (A'.Value = 10)
Thread 1 resumes and wants to swap A with B: CAS(localA, A', B) => but this thread expects that if CAS passes the value of A to be 5; wrong: since CAS passes given that localA and A' have the same memory location but localA.Value!=A'.Value  => thus the operation shouldn't be performed.
```

The thing is that in GC enabled systems this will never happen since `localA` holds a reference to that memory location and thus A' will never get allocated to that memory location.